# How to choose random value of a list 5 times and give a different value each time

Tags: python

I am new to python, so forgive me if my question seems dumb. I am trying to make a program that asks a different math question each time in a for loop which is set to repeat 5 times. But I am kinda stuck here. It repeats the same question each time the for loop is run but I am trying to show a different question each time. Is there any way in which it's possible to do it the way I want?

```
qst = random.choice(qsts)
crt = 0
for x in range(5):
    x += 1
    print("Question " + str(x))
    print(" ")
    print(qst)
```

Comment: You have to place the line that generates the question inside the loop.

Comment: The best way is to call random.shuffle on qsts then you can just extract the elements sequentially. Also, adding 1 to *x* is a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *random* module to shuffle or sample the list of questions. You can then iterate over the list sequentially. For example:

```
from random import shuffle

qsts = ['How high is mount Everest',
'Will England ever win the World Cup',
'Is a tomato a fruit',
'Do you like cabbage',
'Is Windows a terrible operating system']

shuffle(qsts)

for i, q in enumerate(qsts, 1):
    print(f'Question {i}: {q}?')
```

Or, if you don't want the qsts list to change...

```
from random import sample

qsts = ['How high is mount Everest',
'Will England ever win the World Cup',
'Is a tomato a fruit',
'Do you like cabbage',
'Is Windows a terrible operating system']

for i, q in enumerate(sample(qsts, k=len(qsts)), 1):
    print(f'Question {i}: {q}?')
```

**Output sample:**

```
Question 1: How high is mount Everest?
Question 2: Do you like cabbage?
Question 3: Will England ever win the World Cup?
Question 4: Is a tomato a fruit?
Question 5: Is Windows a terrible operating system?
```

Answer (score 2):

You only ever make a choice once, outside the loop. You need to do move that first line into the loop so it's run on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the line that gets a random question inside the for loop might work a bit better, but it's still not the best solution as the same question might randomly get picked twice.

You are better off using `random.sample` to get five elements which are guaranteed all to be unique.

Here is the code:

```py
random_qsts = random.sample(qsts, 5)
crt = 0
for i, q in enumerate(random_qsts, 1):
    print(f"Question {i}: {q}")
```

This code gets all five random questions first, outside of the loop, and then iterates over them, asking each one.

This way, no question will be repeated twice.